# remove last two string char!

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

The following code:

```
If checkboxList.Items(i).Selected Then 
   .Fields("DESC1").Value += checkboxList.Items(i).Text + ", "
End If
```

should produce output such as "A, B, C,(space)", which will then be bound to a dynamically created `GridView`. I would like to remove the last two-char string, that is ",(space)". How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't add them on in the first place :) try

```
If checkboxList.Items(i).Selected Then    
    if .Fields("DESC1").Value Is System.DbNull.Value then
        .Fields("DESC1").Value = checkboxList.Items(i).Text
    else
        .Fields("DESC1").Value +=  ", " + checkboxList.Items(i).Text
    End If
End If
```

Comment: You don't need the += in the first case. It might even be a bug if .Value can be Null.

Comment: I should say, you don't need the + in the +=

Comment: @kibibu: ta pal, well spotted

Comment: it works but "IF String.IsNullOrEmpty(.Fields("DESC1").Value)
" will give error, "Conversion from type "DBNull" to string is invalid". So, i change it to "IF .Fields("DESC1").Value is System.DbNull.Value" then it works! Thanx.....

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx), which may do what you want, without the need to manipulate the final two characters.

Comment: String.Join takes an array of strings. `checkboxList.Items` is a collection class, not array...

Answer (score 3):

For info, string concatenation is expensive. It looks (from the `i` and from the results) like you should really be using a `StringBuilder`; some rough pseudo-code (in C#, but trivial to translate to VB.Net):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0 ; i < checkboxList.Items.Count ; i++) {
    if(checkboxList.Items[i].Selected) {
        if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(", "); // add separator
        sb.Append(checkboxList.Items[i].Text); // add text
    }
}
someOjb.Fields("DESC1") = sb.ToString(); // use result
```

Comment: If you know approximate how long the total string will be, it will be even more efficient to pre-initialize the size of the StringBuilder by something like this (example if each item including separator is approximate 6 chars long): 
`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(6 * checkboxList.Items.Count)` 
 If the size you allocate is close to the actual size at the end, you will end up with little or no need for re-allocation of more memory.

Comment: True, true - but you'd need to know typical text lengths; in the general case it is probably not worth scanning twice - just let the doubling algorithm handle it.

Comment: Awesome solution, Marc - this is the one I implemented.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want to get "A, B, C" from "A, B, C, ". A bit of simple string manipulation should do the job:

```
Dim input = "A, B, C, "
Dim result = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf(","))
```

This is more versatile than simply removing the last two characters, since it looks for the last comma, which is what I believe you are after.

Of course, the fact that you're adding on these two chars in the first place sounds a bit dodgy. I'd need to see more context to show how this can be avoided, however.

Comment: This will throw an exception if input is empty

Answer (score 1):

You can use .TrimEnd(", ".ToCharArray()) on the string, or you can use SubString:

```
strLetters.Substring(0, strLetters.Length - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.Fields("DESC1").Value += checkboxList.Items(i).Text + ", "

. Fields("DESC1").Value = .Fields("DESC1").Value.TrimRight(new []{',',' '});
```

PS:- sorry if it is not valid vb syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also just "Remove":

```
string k = "okay";
string s = k.Remove(k.Length - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all trailing , and/or [space]:

```
.Fields("DESC1").Value = .Fields("DESC1").Value.TrimRight(", ".ToCharArrray())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedValues = checkboxList.Items
    .Where(i => i.Selected)
    .Select(i => i.Fields("DESC1").Value);

var result = String.Join(", ", selectedValues);
```

Answer (score -1):

Does VB have a ternary if operator?

```
If checkboxList.Items(i).Selected Then 
    .Fields("DESC1").Value += checkboxList.Items(i).Text + (i == checkboxList.Items.Length-1 ? "" : ", ")
End If
```

Comment: Yes it does, but that's not it.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct myself, No VB.Net does not an a ternary operator, but there is a function that does something similar to the ?: operator in c#. However as it's a function it'll always evaluate both statements

Comment: VB9 (.NET 3) actually has the ternary operator (as a true operator). It is similar to the old IIf(...) function, but is named only If(...), and can take 2 or 3 parameters.